# Add Firefox "/" and "'" keyboard shortcuts to Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, search, keyboard-navigation

I very recently switched to Chrome, and it generally works fine, but my last problem with it is lack of / and ' shortcuts.

For those that don't know:

- / is more or less like ctrl-f
- ' is like /, but searches only in link texts

The important factor in "more or less" is that in Firefox, when I press enter, and current found string is on links (which is always the case with '-searching) - the link is followed.

So, for example, then I'll go to [reddit.com](http://reddit.com/), and type:

- '
- p
- i
- enter

I will go to "pics" subreddit.

Is there any way to have these shortcuts work in chrome, or, at the very least, make ctrl-f work like / in firefox - i.e. pressing enter would follow link?

Answer (score 0):

The Type-ahead-find extension does all of these things: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/type-ahead-find/cpecbmjeidppdiampimghndkikcmoadk

To following a highlighted link, no extension necessary, hit esc, enter.